# Future<http.Response> what if request response was null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have trying to made global http request class to use it in all my app, I declared method inside class "**webPost**" to return Future<http.Response> but didn't accept null as return, in case request returns null on any exeption , what should I do in this case .

code :

```
class TWebRequest{
  
late int errorCode = -1 ; 
late String errorMessage = ""; 
late bool successed = false;


Future<http.Response> webPost(String url , Object? body , Map<String,String> headers ) async
{

  final http.Response response ;
try {
   response =
      await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: headers ,body:  body);
  return  response;
  
} on SocketException {
  errorCode = 10000 ;
  errorMessage = "SocketException";
} on HttpException {
  errorCode = 10001 ;
  errorMessage = "HttpException";
} on FormatException {
 errorCode = 10002 ;
 errorMessage = "FormatException";
 return null ; //not accept 
}
finally { 
}

} //end void 
} //end class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Future<http.Response>` is declared - this means that it can only return non-nullable. Use `Future<http.Response?>` to allow nullable return value.